# Obtain hardcopy from a screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a job launched in a screen session which is expected to run for several hours. From time to time I'm requested to check if job is still running and guess at wich % of work is.

Guess if it is working or not is as simple as perform a `ps -fu $LOGNAME`to check if the process is still alive, but in order to guess the % I need to check the output of the program (it outputs some information which can be used with `grep -n` to see which line of file it is currently processing).

I can attach the session (`screen -R jobLoadItems`) and take a look to it, but I would like to do it without attaching to session again. I already checked to perform inside the screen session <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to activate screenlog but it's so verbooooooooose it will take all disk space available.

So there is a way to just print last lines of the screen session without attaching to it? (something like `screen -S jobLoadItem -Q display last 50 lines`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
 screen  -r <name of sesion> -X hardcopy
```

this is same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>

from the man page:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>      (hardcopy)
>   Write a hardcopy of the current window to the                              file "hardcopy.n".

Comment: How do I mention my own file name with -X?